# 'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in 'com.krish.galaxypdfviewer.MainActivity

Tags: java, android, pdf-viewer

I added a button and tried to link it with my 2nd activity name 'website' but its saying
onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined i dont know how to fix
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aQzn.png)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        defineView();
        handleIntent();
        defineActionBar();
        checkPermission();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openWebsite();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openWebsite() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Website.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: You have **two** `onCreate(Bundle)` methods. You can have only one. You either need to merge them or delete one of them.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as error messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in this activity](/q/28452194/90527)

Comment: As per the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) in the [help], please [search](/help/searching) before posting. See also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `onCreate()` Method for two times, you need to remove one of them.

what you can do is cut this code from the second `onCreate()` and paste it to the first one.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openWebsite();
            }
        });
```

So your final `onCreate()` code will be like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        
        defineView();
        handleIntent();
        defineActionBar();
        checkPermission();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openWebsite();
            }
        });
    }



    public void openWebsite() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Website.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```